# Size of object and C++ standard

Tags: c++, object, serialization

Looking around I found many places where the way to get the size of a certain object (class or struct) is explained. I read about the padding, about the fact that virtual function table influences the size and that "pure method" object has size of 1 byte. However I could not find whether these are facts about implementation or C++ standard (at least I was not able to find all them).

In particular I am in the following situation: I'm working with some data which are encoded in some  objects. These objects do *not* hold pointers to other data. They do not inherit from any other class, but they have some methods (non virtual). I have to put these data in a buffer to send them via some socket. Now reading what I mentioned above, I simply copy my objects on the sender buffer, noticing that the data are "serialized" correctly, i.e. each member of the object is copied, and methods do not affect the byte structure.

I would like to know if what I get is just because of the implementation of the compiler or if it is prescribed by the standard.

Comment: Read more on serialization here ; https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/serialization. Note when you receive your data on the "other side" casting it to an object pointer will not result in an object instance (new is not called) and you will not have a valid object. You would need to create a constructor that can use the data to create a valid instance. (You can also have a look at C++20's bitcast)

Comment: [Objects and alignment](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/object) discusses alignment and padding (slightly) and has references at the bottom. Depending on what your data are, alignment and padding may be constant across systems, or they may be different. Using specified-bit-width integers is safer than using implementation-defined types like `int` or `long`. Different architectures will represent multi-byte integers with different endianess. Etc. etc. A microcontroller I'm working on has 32-bit max alignment, so 64 bit numbers are 32-bit aligned.

Comment: Without knowing how you've encoded the data from your objects into the buffer that is sent over a socket, it's impossible to say.    It's not only about vtables (which are not required by the standard, BTW, even though most modern compilers use them in `class`/`struct` types that have virtual functions) or padding.  It's about ANY assumptions you've made that may not be universally true on all compilers (e.g. size of an `int`, endianness, floating point format, etc).

Comment: You could simply send JSON that describes the object, and then it doesn't matter what language on the other side is reading the data.  It's up to the language to figure out what the JSON is stating, and create the relevant object(s) from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The memory layouts of classes are **not specified in the C++ standard** precisely. Even the memory layout of scalar objects such as integers aren't specified. They are up to the language implementation to decide, and generally depend on the underlying hardware. The standard does specify restrictions that the implementation specific layout must satisfy.

If a type is trivially copyable, then it can be "serialised" by copying its memory into a buffer, and it can be de-it serialised back as you describe. However, such trivial serialisation only works when the process that de-serialises uses the same memory layout. This cannot generally be assumed to be the case since the other process may be running on entirely different hardware and may have been compiled with a different (version of) compiler.

Comment: Thank you very much. Well, the "de-serialisation" is not matter of concern to me since, on the receiver side data are probably encapsulated more conveniently in a different manner.

Answer (score 1):

You should use POD (plain-old-data). A structure is POD if it hasn't virtual table, some constructors, private methods and many other things.
There is garantee the pod data is placed in memory in declaration order.
There is alignment in pod data. And you should specify right alignment (it's your decision). See #pragma pack (push, ???).

Comment: Although alignment is 'your decision' you better decide to use a value that's a multiple of the lowest common denominator of all platforms you are expecting it run on. (Some platforms will fault on data that isn't natively aligned.